# How to leave my company on good terms, when planning to join a competitor?

Tags: professionalism, united-states, quitting, leadership

I've held a good job over the last several years, but now I am planning to make a move and join a competitor that will allow me to become a Team Lead - in particular, I am looking to join a competitor that is based in my hometown.

How do I best leave on good terms with the management team?  I have not spoken to them about it but am instead choosing to stay radio silent, at the moment.  I am no longer comfortable communicating with our current Team Lead.

(Although they do know of my desire to leave soon, but mostly through secondhand sources, e.g. from social media outlets.)

Comment: Contracts often have a clause about not joining a direct competitor for some time, eg. 6 months after quitting. Have you checked yours?

Comment: if you don't want to be identified, i would remove the locations you've mentioned

Comment: [How much should I reveal about a new job after resigning from my current job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10280/how-much-should-i-reveal-about-a-new-job-after-resigning-from-my-current-job) touches on this (although I'm not sure it's a duplicate). Don't bring it up until you have a signed contract with your new employer and you're handing in your resignation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Staying silent is rarely going to lead to a positive relationship after you leave. Openness and honesty is a much better option:

- let your boss know that the reason you are leaving is for progression and location, not from a desire to join the position as such

That should defuse resentment - but be aware they still may be upset, especially if you are a good employee. Not much you can do about that though.