# Should I tell my colleagues/employer the details of my new employer?

Tags: new-job, employer-relations

I work in Germany. I am leaving my current company for another better paid position along with other benefits.

I never thought telling your colleagues and/or employer about the new company is a problem. But here I have noticed that nobody leaving this company wants to share this information.

My colleagues (who are friendly with me) are obviously interested in knowing where I am off to.

Are there any possible downsides of sharing this information?

UPDATE: What could be the reason that most people here (my current company) have not shared this information. Could it be a cultural thing? 
I remember I asked someone (relatively close) and he said I am going to a company with many people and would not name the company despite my direct inquiry.

Why my question is different: The other question is talking about official communication to the old company through filling a form. My question is that should I tell me colleagues who ask me personally, this has nothing to do with an official request. My current company officially has not asked any details about my new company.

Comment: [This answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/14314/8234) from the linked question appears to do a decent job of going into why some people might not want to share this information.

Comment: If that is what is happening at your current company, then I would personally do the same. There may be someone in Management known to have been vindictive in the past.

Comment: No, say **nothing**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is going to be largely opinion based, but there's no reason not to let your employer/colleagues know where you're going.  They're going to find out from your LinkedIn profile (or whatever social media you update).

Moving on is a fairly natural thing to do, and people are curious about where you're headed to.

Not telling them seems to be a bit impolite, or gives them the impression that they're part of the reason you're leaving...

Comment: Yet, if it seems common in this specific company that nobody else is doing it, there *could* be a reason for that, which is perhaps not so obvious... I'd be careful, too. In a company where all the people that go freely share the info, I'd not care so much, probably. I really can't see how being careful is "impolite", though. I'd probably say something like "I'll tell you after hours ;) "

Comment: @Fildor The OP added this information after I initially posted this answer.

Comment: Oh, ok. I wasn't aware of that. In that case you might want to expand your answer to address it?

Answer (score 5):

> Are there any possible downsides of sharing this information?

Nope, feel free to share the information **after** your leave, **outside** of either working environment.  Either share the information over beers after your last day of work, or during a friendly lunch meeting after your departure.

**Short answer**:  Share info after you leave outside of either work place.

Comment: Just wondering, why does it matter if you wait until the end of your last day vs. sometime during your notice period?

Comment: Typically this information is better to be released before any potential retaliation action from your current employer can occur.   It is just safer and cleaner for you.  It also helps prevent the image that you are trying to take other employees with you.

Comment: A bit paranoid.

Comment: @AndreiROM or a bit safe.  All about what your past experience has been.  Being safe never bit me in the ass.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar situation. Over my two week notice I had a lot of people ask me where I was going, and in the beginning I simply stated "a place closer to home".

But I discussed the new position in detail with my team mates, and they were very happy for me. By the time the two weeks were up people were pretty much aware of where I was going, and no one felt any sort of animosity toward me.

Unless someone is really our to ruin your chances there's not much danger in letting people know. However, realize that once you tell even one person the cat's out of the bag.

There's also a question as to *how* you tell them. Anything along the lines of **"I'm going to X Company, which is why better than *this place*"** should be kept to yourself.